# How to understand errors in my Dockerfile running Angular

Tags: angular, docker, npm, dockerfile

I'm the totalest noob to Docker (while rather comfy with the rest of tech stack). Following roughly [the Docker guide](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/), I've landed in the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM angular/ngcontainer:latest
WORKDIR /ClientApp
COPY . .
RUN npm install --global @angular/cli
RUN npm install
CMD ["ng", "serve"]
```

I've checked and **tried** to understand all the [best practices for Dockerfile design](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/). Then, I created my images and started it like this (relying on the pre-existing image [angular/ngcontainer](https://hub.docker.com/r/angular/ngcontainer)).

```
docker build --tag ng-poc .
dock run --detach --publish 4343:4200 --name NgPocky --interactive ng-poc
```

It fails giving me the error log below. What I gather from it is that the *ng* command isn't found. When I tried the global add on my machine, it worked, so I suspect that it might be an error due to my lack of understanding how global the command becomes in a Linux environment (and/or errors in the Dockerfile itself, of course).

> /home/circleci/.npm-global/bin/ng: line 2: use strict: command not found
> /home/circleci/.npm-global/bin/ng: line 4: //: Is a directory
> /home/circleci/.npm-global/bin/ng: line 5: //: Is a directory
> /home/circleci/.npm-global/bin/ng: line 6: try: command not found
> /home/circleci/.npm-global/bin/ng: ng: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
> /home/circleci/.npm-global/bin/ng: ng: line 7: ` process.title = 'ng ' + Array.from(process.argv).slice(2).join(' ');'

Not sure how to troubleshoot it further at this point.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the fact that this [angular/ngcontainer](https://hub.docker.com/r/angular/ngcontainer) is 2 years old, and likely out of date. Find a newer image/container to work from.

Comment: @R.Richards I have no reference to "old" in regard to dockering, so I appreciate your comment. What's confusing me is how to discriminate between the different alternatives out there. I expected Google to provide a go-to image, a recommended builder plate to start with. Ultimately, I want to run **my** environment and not some random dude's. But it's not clear to me where to get the most vanilla, pristine and plain basic case to put in my *FROM*. (And apparently, I picked wrongly.) Thoughts on that?

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't work with angular. You must this to an image like a SO (or a `sysprep` SO). With this in mind, I suggest you to start (read: FROM) an ubuntu image. On DockerHub you find prepared images: you must read the CONTENT of the image on description or better if the image has a GitHub repo where you can look at the Dockerfile and understand which contains.

Comment: @Max Thanks. It helped. IN fact, you **not** coming from Angular direction is an advantage in this case. I want to grasp a better understanding of how Docker operates and **then** apply it on .NET/Angular-combo. So technological agnosticism is preferred. That being said, wouldn't it make sense to `FROM node`, compile the project producing the executable artifacts and then `FROM nginx` to serve them? Or is it generally a less painful approach to go with vanilla Ubuntu, install NodeJs on it and do all the magic there? I'm fine with opinionated input too.   :)

Comment: First is preferable (in my opinion). FROM node -> build then FROM nginx -> serve. A typically [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds). Notice the `COPY --from`

Comment: @Max Cool. You just confirmed my hunch, making it more likely to be the proper approach. Do you want to post an answer collecting the info from the comments so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must think to an image like a SO (or a sysprep SO).
The `FROM ubuntu:latest` is like *get an ubuntu operating system then ...*

On DockerHub you find already prepared images (like the above ubuntu) or other images with more contents like the python image who starting from `alpine` distro added the python language support.

You can know the CONTENT of the image reading the description or better the `Dockerfile` on GitHub if the image has a GitHub repo.

With this in mind, I suggest you to use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds)

For your problem you can:

> Warning ! Pseudocode

```
FROM node:12 as build
WORKDIR /clientApp
COPY . .
RUN npm install --global @angular/cli
RUN npm build

FROM nginx:latest as runtime
COPY --from=build /compiledoutput /usr/share/nginx/html
```

For speedup build a better approach is to create a custom image with only `@angular/cli` like this

```
FROM node:12
RUN npm install --global @angular/cli@11.1.14
```

`docker build -t angularcli:11.1.14 .`

And then instead of getting the node12 you can write

```
FROM angularcli:11.1.14 as build
WORKDIR /clientApp
COPY . .
# Not necessary -> RUN npm install --global @angular/cli
RUN npm build

FROM nginx:latest as runtime
COPY --from=build /compiledoutput /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: Wow! This reply actually got even better than the collected contents of the comments. Awesome. Just to verify - the setup you describe consists of a single container running, right? One that compiles the stuff and serves them in one, smooth dockerization (though built on a two-step schema).